# ios imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: not called after stopVideoCapture

Tags: ios

I'm creating custom overlay view for video recording.

I've add a button to start/stop recording:

```
[takePhotoBut addTarget:imagePickerController action:@selector(toogleRecord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which calls `[super startVideoCapture];` or `[super stopVideoCapture];` in my custom `UIImagePickerController`. Also I've set delegate

```
    CustomPickerController *imagePickerController= [[CustomPickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
```

and I expect to get notified about `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`, but I get no response. I believe it happens, because ios wait till user clicks "Use video". But I want to get notified without user clicking that button. Are there any workarounds??

**EDIT 1**

the way I'm presenting ImagePicker:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It is not property on my VC.

Comment: you should modify your question to show how you are presenting your `imagePickerController` object.  Also, I wonder if your controller is being released by ARC early? Can you make `imagePickerController` a property of your view controller (the view controller that's the delegate)?

Comment: try making it a property and see what happens...

Comment: i too have this same problem. got this fixed??

Comment: Same problem in iOS 10, using Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your imagePickerController `cameraCaptureMode` set to `UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo`

```
imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
```

This solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Fixed it by hiding the camera controls.

`imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.